# Keras Error classweights wont support for 3D+ data

Tags: keras

I'm trying to do semantic segmentation with ***`segnet`*** in ***`keras`***, while giving class_weights for `fit()` method as dictionary it gives `class_weight` won't support for 3D+ data, OK we need to give sample_weights, but if I give class_weights as a list its working.can we give class_weights as list instead of `sample_weights`, of course not as dictionary?